# Как передать сообщение в callback?

Tags: python, telebot

Нужно передать текст сообщения в callback_query_handler для вызова функции, как это можно реализовать?

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_info(message):
    inf_0 = message.text.lower()
    res = []
    if message.text.lower() == "Info":
            get_info(inf=inf_0, result=res)
            bot.send.message(message.chat.id, res, reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
    def callback(call):
        info_get_two(message.text)
```

Comment: используйте register_next_step_handler